# Why is a MAUI custom control with no code not the same as the base control?

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI control called `UnmodifiedEntry` I'm trying to migrate from Forms. I have moved it to a new MAUI app to isolate it. Right now it has no code in it, it's just an empty class in common code:

```cs
namespace MauiTestApp.Controls;

public  class UnmodifiedEntry : Entry
{
}
```

I have it on a XAML page along with a regular entry:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout x:Name="LoginEntryLayout"
                 HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                 BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                 Padding="10">
    <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="UnmodifiedEntryLayout"
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     BackgroundColor="Bisque"
                     Padding="10">
        <Label x:Name="UnmodifiedEntryLabel"
                   Text="UnmodifiedEntry"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   FontSize="16" />
        <controls:UnmodifiedEntry x:Name="UnmodifiedEntry"
                               WidthRequest="200"
                               Text=""
                               BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="EntryLayout"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                BackgroundColor="Bisque"
                Padding="10">
        <Label x:Name="EntryLabel"
               Text="Regular Entry"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontSize="16" />
        <Entry x:Name="Entry"
               WidthRequest="200"
               Text=""
               BackgroundColor="LightPink"
               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

When I run on iOS the entries are not the same, the unmodified one has a different height:

[image]

What is causing the difference?

Comment: Is there a CustomRenderer that it's modifying the "UnmodifiedEntry" behaviour? Or maybe a handler that is changing the "Entry" behaviour in your MAUI project? You can search for the custom renderers into the iOS native project on Xamarin. For the handlers check docs to know what to look for in your MAUI project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: No, I edited my question to add that I have moved this code into a File .. new Maui app.  The only modifications that I have made are the additions to the xaml file and the empty custom control definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles for the default MAUI app template's controls aren't applied to derived types. So if you don't have any mappers or renderers that change the appearance of a specific type, then this *could* be the reason.

You can try this by finding the *Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml* file and changing the following from

```xml
<Style TargetType="Editor">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

to

```xml
<Style TargetType="Editor"
       ApplyToDerivedTypes="true">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

You can find more info about this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml#apply-a-style-to-derived-types).

Alternatively, you may need to register the same handler for your custom control as the base control in *MauiProgram.cs*:

```cs
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(h =>
{
    h.AddHandler<UnmodifiedEntry, EntryHandler>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also found deleting all the styles worked as well.  Since this is all new I'm now trying to determine if I need the styles or not.

Comment: I would recommend keeping the styles, but that's up to you. I'm glad you managed to "fix" the issue.